# mcrypt_encrypt not working properly on PHP 5.6.9

Tags: php, encryption, mcrypt, php-5.6

I have the following code which worked fine on PHP 5.5.9.

```
function index()
{
    echo $this->encryptText_3des('TEST','JHHKJH9879');
}

function encryptText_3des($plainText, $key) {
    $key = hash("md5", $key, TRUE); 
    for ($x=0;$x<8;$x++) {
        $key = $key.substr($key, $x, 1);
    }
    $padded = $this->pkcs5_pad($plainText,
    mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_3DES, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC));
    $encrypted = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_3DES, $key, $padded, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC));
    return $encrypted;
}

function pkcs5_pad ($text, $blocksize)  
{
    $pad = $blocksize - (strlen($text) % $blocksize);
    return $text . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
}
```

The encryption was happening fine.But in 5.6.9, the in the PHP doc of mcrypt_encrypt, they mention that

> Invalid key and iv sizes are no longer accepted. mcrypt_encrypt() will now throw a warning and return FALSE if the inputs are invalid. Previously keys and IVs were padded with '\0' bytes to the next valid size.

How will I modify my current code with the fifth parameter without altering the encryption algorithm?

I tried

```
$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_3DES, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
```

and given $iv as fifth parameter.

But it didn't work out. The encryption was different from the earlier one.

Answer (score 4):

Don't emulate old PHP versions weak behaviour for initializing IV.

Use [`mcrypt_create_iv()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mcrypt-create-iv.php).

They removed the auto zero-byte iv for a **reason**.

Comment: While I agree that a random IV should be used, it may not be applicable to the OPs case, because they already have a library full of ciphertexts which must be compatible.

Comment: @ArtjomB. good point, to ensure decryption of "legacy" ciphertexts, the "old" iv must be used..

Comment: Make sure you use `MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM` too!

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer in case anyone need

```
$ivSize = 8; 
$iv = str_repeat("\0", $ivSize);

$encrypted = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_3DES, $key, $padded, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));
```

Pass a 5th parameter manually which the earlier version was doing on its own!

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you against reinventing the wheel as your function has numerous cryptography engineering flaws.

- Don't use 3DES, use AES. The correct mcrypt constant for AES is `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128`, regardless of your desired key size. [Mcrypt is pretty terrible](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/if-you-re-typing-word-mcrypt-into-your-code-you-re-doing-it-wrong).
- Don't use `md5()` as a key derivation function. If you find yourself needing a KDF (e.g. because you're using a password instead of storing an encryption key), use `hash_pbkdf2()` with SHA-256.
- You are encrypting but not authenticating your ciphertext. [Secret-key encryption without message authentication is **NOT** secure in any language](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/using-encryption-and-authentication-correctly)! Encrypt-Then-MAC please.

If you're going to use mcrypt (our recommendations for [secure data encryption in PHP](https://paragonie.com/white-paper/2015-secure-php-data-encryption) are to use libsodium if you can; otherwise [defuse/php-encryption](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption); otherwise openssl), make sure you pass the correct constant to `mcrypt_create_iv()`.

**Bad**:

```
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_RAND); // BAD EXAMPLE
```

**Good**:

```
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM); // YES!
```